# WPF DataGrid CellStyle implicit style applied instead of explicit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Defined implicit DataGridCell style is applied instead of the explicit style set via DataGrid's style (DataGrid.CellStyle property). Why? How does the XAML evaluate, whether to use Implicit style over Explicit in this case?

I am trying to create DataGrid style, which will also set the DataGridCells' style.

Tried removing the Implicit DataGridCell style and everything works as expected, explicit style gets working properly.

How to make them work together?

Also providing the DataGridCell style as DataGrid's style resource works. How? Why?

Implicit Style of the DataGridCell

```
<!-- Implicit DataGridCell style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Style of the DataGridCell, which I want to apply

```
<!-- Explicit DataGridCellStyle -->
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                         MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3b85c8" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0668b7" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Style of the DataGrid

```
<!-- DataGrid style -->
<Style x:Key="BaseDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" />

    <!-- Uncommenting this makes the solution works even with Implicit style -->
    <!--<Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"/>
    </Style.Resources>-->

</Style>
```

Simple Datagrid instance

```
<!-- Data grid itself -->
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource BaseDataGrid}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ModelClasses}">
</DataGrid>
```